# Does there exist a complete list of Polymer "on-..." events?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm just wondering if there is any documentation that will list all of the "on-..." events that are available in Polymer.

I'm talking about when you have code such as:

```
<div class="clickable" on-click="clickDiv"></div>
```

I know there exists things like:

- on-tap
- on-click
- etc...

I have looked at the Polymer documentation and only seen a list for gestures, rather than what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some information [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events) but its not a complete list its what polymer recommends you to use.

Comment: That's what I'd previously seen Pascal. But I want to know only the "on-.." events. A shame they didn't bother to think about it!

Comment: Well generally polymer does not create any new events its actually just wrapping default browser events for you so that you can write on-... instead of document.addEventListener thats why i would suggest you have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events which is a list of all browser events. They all should work with on-...

Comment: Thanks for the info Pascal